Set environment in Visual Studio for pyqgis in Windows
I want to set the environemnt that works in visual studio 2022 (for Python) with Windows 10 for pyqgis 3.9.
I found the solution creating a "set_qgis_env.bat" with this content.
set PATH=C:\ProgrammiAC\QGIS3.28\apps\Python39;%PATH%
set PYTHONPATH=C:\ProgrammiAC\QGIS3.28\apps\qgis-ltr\python;C:\ProgrammiAC\QGIS3.28\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins;C:\ProgrammiAC\QGIS3.28\apps\Qt5\plugins;C:\ProgrammiAC\QGIS3.28\apps\Python39\Lib\site-packages

rem modify the path if necessary
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

If I run manually "set_qgis_env.bat" visual studio open automatically with the right environment.
I am not completely happy with this solution because I don't want to run the "set_qgis_env.bat" manually, but I want that when I open visual studio (sln) it run automatically. Visual Studio must be able to run the bat file alone when I open it.
I thounght to have the solution. I added on the visual studio 2022 solution and with property>>>Debug>>>Script Argument I added the path of "set_qgis_env.bat"
enter image description here
It does not work because when I close and reopen the visual studio solution has no environment.
I know that there is a second solution: to add "enviroment variables" alone.
enter image description here
Again, it does not work!
Is there a problem of semantic for PATH and PYTHONPATH? No, because "set_qgis_env.bat" manually works. Furthermore if I add the environment variable in windows with the same paths of "set_qgis_env.bat", when I open visual studio the environment is OK, but it is not my wished solution because after I have problem with the script in the python console of QGIS.enter image description here
Question: What is the problem and how can I set the environment every time that I open visual studio 2022?

I followed your instructions: property>>>Debug>Environment Variable and add a env Variable  for test. To verify that the environment variable is in effect, i use os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] to print it when debugging my code.
import os
path = os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
print(path)


Based on the testing result, i think "Properties->Debug" provides properties you can set to configure the running behavior for the debugger. It seems that it may not able to set up a python environment for your project in non-debug mode.
If you want to set an environment for you project, you can  open Add Environment dialog, select the Existing environment tab. Expand the Environment dropdown list and choose your desired environment, then select Add. For more information, please refer to doc
(Note: if there is any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.)
Hope it can help you.

environment has already been created as you show in your answer! The problem is that every python.exe file is not able to find qgis.core module independently and need to call the bat file before to run. Maybe my question should be done in different way. How to integrate qgis specific enviroment for pyqgis in the python interpreter? If I take the interpreter directly outside visual studio when I try to import in python3 the qgis.core module there is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'", but the qgis module I assume are here: C:\ProgrammiAC\QGIS3.28\apps\qgis-ltr\python
@Dou Xu-MSFT

To be clear, I don't want never run bat file or write something before every time. I have found a way, it is to set enviroment variable in windows, but the python console in QGIS stop working. So, even this solution did not satisfy me and in visual studio again it seems that every time I have to run MANUALLY a bat file.

Hi @Simon Sorry for misunderstanding your question. I understand what you mean now.
